# Unable to use an array as an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am in the process of building a software download site for my company.

However, I have come across a problem that I am unsure how to get past.

I am retrieving all the information from a table about a particular software release and placing them in a multidimensional array. I am then trying to run a foreach (I have even tried a for loop) against that array and I get an error shown below:
[image: Error Message]

When I run var dump against the original array, I get this:

[image: Var Dump Results]

So I am really confused as I don't know what I'm missing or where I am going wrong. The reason why I want to run this is so that I can filter the array into a one dimensional array.

Below is the code for the main web page

```
<?php
  //Displays list of companies in 2 columns
  $versionAccess = VersionAccess::findAccess($relId);//This gets set earlier in the webpage
  $count = count($versionAccess);
  var_dump($versionAccess);
  foreach ($versionAccess as $va)
  {
    if ($va->company_access != '0')
    {
      $versionAcc[] = $va->comapny_id;
    }
  }
  foreach ($company as $compAccess)
  {
    $compAccessId = $compAccess->company_id;
    if (in_array($compAccessId, $versionAcc))
    {
      $access = 'checked disabled';
    }
    else { $access = 'disabled'; }
    $accessName = 'access'.$compAccessId;
    if ($ctr % 2 == 0)
    {
      echo '<td>'.$compAccess->company_name.':</td>';
      echo '<td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="'.$accessName.'" value="1" '.$access.'><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    else
    {
      if ($ctr < $compCount)
      {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$compAccess->company_name.':</td>';
         echo '<td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="'.$accessName.'" value="1" '.$access.'><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>';
      }
      else
      {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$compAccess->company_name.':</td>';
         echo '<td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="'.$accessName.'" value="1" '.$access.'><span class="slider round"></span></label></td>';
         echo '</tr>';
       }
    }
    $ctr++;
  }
?>
```

The function that brings the data from the database is:

```
public static function findAccess($accessId)
//find the version access in database
{
    return self::findQuery("SELECT * FROM version_access WHERE version_id = '$accessId'");
}
```

The findQuery method:

```
public static function findQuery($sql)
{
    global $database;

    $resultSet = $database->query($sql);
    $objectArray = array();
    while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet))
    {
        $objectArray[] = self::instant($row);
    }
    return $objectArray;
}
```

I am still relatively new and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is line 303 pointed at in the error message ?

Comment: @Calimero It points at the first foreach loop - foreach ($versionAccess as $va)

Comment: Well, and *does* `VersionAccess` implement any of [`ArrayAccess`](//php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) or iterator interfaces?

Comment: that would tell us $versionAccess doesn't contain an array (although the var_dump() indicates) but a single, plain VersionAccess object instead. The reason of this probably being in the findQuery() method, but I can't say for sure without its code.

Comment: @Calimero please see the above edits I have made with the method that you requested. However I have used this method in all my classes including the company class which I loop through successfully

Comment: Thanks for the edit (Nothing wrong there), can you edit again and add the var_dump() call as well.

Comment: @Calimero I have added it

Comment: Well, that's just not possible afaik and I'm at a loss there, sorry. Anything interesting about the environment you might not be telling us ?

Comment: @Calimero I'm running in a local server (easyPHP) but nothing I'm aware of

Comment: @mwweb what does this do?

Comment: @NickFallows noo my bad. so line 303 is `foreach ($versionAccess as $va)`?

Comment: @mwweb that is correct

Comment: not sure but what about `foreach ($versionAccess as $key =>$va)`